# Ember.js Plugin that handles common authorization use cases

Tags: ember.js, plugins

I'm loosing a lot of time to implement pretty common scenarios in website development. So, I'm looking for ember plugin that handles common use cases in authorization process for Ember.js framework. Use cases are:

- Registration
- Email verification
- Login
- Ask for password reset
- Password reset
- Logout

Does plugin like that exist? I would like to type in command line: ember install authentication and it should generate all necessary files. (views, controllers, components)

Comment: The majority of those tasks are server-side intensive. That is why you don't see any Ember JS plugins that handle them for you. They should be handled primarily by your APIs.

Comment: But, that is at least 5 views that need to be implemented and even more different decisions on the way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle some part in your Ember app and some part login authentication in your server app. However, I would recommend this library which I am using in my apps time to time and it's awesome. It almost covers all about what you want and what you need in Authorization and Authentication

Take a look at [Ember Simple Authorization](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth)

It's pretty easy to install

```
git clone https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth.git
cd ember-simple-auth
npm install && bower install && ember serve
```

then

```
ember install ember-simple-auth
```

Once the library is installed, the session service can be injected wherever needed in the application.

```
// app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session')

  …
});
{{!-- app/templates/application.hbs --}}
<div class="menu">
  …
  {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
    <a {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Logout</a>
  {{else}}
    {{#link-to 'login'}}Login{{/link-to}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
<div class="main">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

You login for example

```
{{!-- app/templates/login.hbs --}}
<form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  <label for="identification">Login</label>
  {{input id='identification' placeholder='Enter Login' value=identification}}
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  {{input id='password' placeholder='Enter Password' type='password' value=password}}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  {{#if errorMessage}}
    <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
  {{/if}}
</form>

// app/controllers/login.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    authenticate() {
      let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', identification, password).catch((reason) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

read more here: http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html